# No option to send Photos to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I want to backup the photos I have in an iPhone 8 (iOS 14.6) with iCloud, but I don't see the option anywhere.

In Settings -> Apple ID -> iCloud, I see a list of apps using iCloud, with toggles to enable or disable it for each app, but Photos doesn't show there.
If I search "iCloud" in the search bar in settings, it shows "Photos | Apple ID -> iCloud", but when I select it, it shows me that same list that I mentioned above.
If I go to Settings -> Photos, I also don't see any option to sync them with iCloud.
And if I select any picture, it also doesn't show my any option to send it to iCloud.
In icloud.com -> Photos, it tells me to go to iCloud photos in my device and turn it on, but like I said, I don't see that option.

How can I enable it?

Comment: Please add screenshots of the screens from System Preferences so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. My iPhone (14.6) displays under Settings > Photos following:

[image]